# can't watch flash content on ubuntu14.10

Tags: flash, streaming

I am trying to watch Starz over the INTERNET on my laptop. Keep getting error message telling I need at least Adobe flash player v11.8. I have searched and searched, seems to be no such thing exists. I have gotten very tired of GREEDY Mr. Gates. But not only can I not play any of the games I paid good money for, now I find I can't watch my programs when I'm away from my house. At least I Could with Windows.Is there a solution to this problem. Keep in mind I am not a programmer and very new to Ubuntu. Otherwise I am very happy with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you don't have flash installed or just need a later version.

You can install flash by opening the `Ubuntu Software Center` (on the launcher to the left and looks like a shopping bag) , search for "flash" then install the "Adobe Flash plug-in". Once you have installed the plugin restart your browser and flash applications should be working fine.

You can also use Google Chrome/ium for browsing (both come with flash in it). You can install Chromium from the Ubuntu Software Center or you can download Chrome [here](http://google.com/chrome), double click the .deb file when its downloaded and then it will install itself through the software center.

Hope this has helped you.

Answer (score 1):

As [Adobe Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/de/software/flash/about/) states only Chrome and Chromium browsers support verions of flash later than 11.2. So I guess you'll have to install Chrome or Chromium.

I am using Chromium 39 from the standard repositories plus the pepperflashplugin.

Start the Ubuntu Software Centre and search for "Chromium Web Browser", click the result to select it and click install.

Furthermore search for "pepper flash" and install the "Pepper Flash Player - browser plugin".

I hope this helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Chrom(e/ium) with Pepper Flash is to use the Windows Flash plugin under a special edition of Wine (which stays separate from any other Wine you might have installed) via a package called Pipelight.  I've got this installed on two Kubuntu 14.04 systems and it works very well -- and supports many more plugins than just Flash.  It works with Mozilla browsers (Firefox, SeaMonkey, IceApe, IceWeasel), since Chrome doesn't need it.

If you don't find Pipelight in the Ubuntu repositories, Google for it; it has its own repository hosted by the developers and once you enable that, installs just like any other Debian/Ubuntu package (after which you need to issue a few commands from terminal, one-time).